# While building a unit test project, VS 2010 cannot find the referenced assembly for testing

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, assembly-resolution

I'm developing a unit test project (let's say XXX.UnitTest) to test ViewModels in another project (XXX) in my solution. I can add the reference but when I build, an error states that it cannot find that same project (XXX)

> Error 42  Could not load file or
>   assembly 'XXX, Version=1.0.2.66,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file
>   specified.    XXX.UnitTest

- I did a clean rebuild of all projects in my solution.
- I verified that the assembly with that version number (1.0.2.66) did exist in the path I was referencing.
- I removed and re-added the reference both as a project and through the Browse tab.
- I made sure that the version number was not specified in the csproj file.
- I verified the referenced assembly with Dependency Walker.
- I verified that both projects were targeting the x86 platform. (As suggested here [Tips to help debug "Could not load file or assembly X or one of its dependencies"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263580/tips-to-help-debug-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-x-or-one-of-its-dependencies))

Does anyone know what else can cause this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem and expect solution too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last week I had this same problem. It turns out my solution and projects were on a network resource. If I moved the solution to the local drive, the problem went away.

- This problem happened regardless if I used a mapped drive or an UNC path.
- This problem happened even with a Code Access Security Policy of "Full Trust" for the URL.
- I believe the problem occurs on *Windows XP* computers and not *Windows 7* computers, but have not tested or verified.
- I believe it has something to do with the **Share** permissions.

  - If I try to use "offline folders" for the network resource, I get "access is denied".

  -.
- Setting NTFS permissions has no effect.
- Adding user to administrators group has no effect.
- I did not test to see if problem exists on removable local drives.

#### Work Around

Move solution and projects to a local hard drive.

#### Comment

I think this is a bug in *Visual Studio 2010*.

Comment: I found a temporary fix was to reference the assembly in the working folder, which in this case is a deployment folder I am debugging out of. Your fix seems to be related and interesting, in that it is also path-related.

Comment: I have to award this answer as the closest thing there is to a solution. It appears that it must be worked around by changing to local paths. In my case however the drive was already local, but I had to change the reference to the deployed assembly in my local drive.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post while searching for the answer. Here is the solution. In the config file of QTAgent32.exe and devenv.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE, add the following element to the  section:

```
<runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" /> 
</runtime>
```

This can be added to machine config file (C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\ machine.config) for all VS2010 tools. Be sure to run notepad as administrator to allow machine.config to save.

See this link for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. This wasn't a Web project but a WPF project. Unfortunately I am not working in this environment. So I cannot tell try any new fixes.

Comment: Wow, I've been searching everywhere for the same problem. This one really works for referencing assemblies from a network drive!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I'm running VS 2010 on Windows Server 2003; both running within a VM on a Mac. My VS project is in the mac home folder (~/) which is mapped as Z:\ from the Windows side. At build time, VS studio generates an error saying it can't find the UnitTests.dll or one of its dependencies. I get the same error with a small test project. If I move the project to the Windows C:\ drive, the dll reference resolves and unit tests work. I tried to add the reference Blanthor mentions, but couldn't get it to work.